# How to get browser keystore from applet?

Tags: browser, applet, keystore

I have an applet for The digital signature.Also i have certificate on PKCS ♯12 which imported to browser. 

**How can i get this certificate from browser using applet?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null, null); 
Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);
```

For more info, check [the docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html).